# MakeFile.am: Mixing c and c++, new errors

Tags: c++, c, makefile, autotools

We have good code base in "c". Now, we are moving to c++ for all new modules. I have a case to use few c++ classes in old c code base. Individually, both works i.e., c++ module and c module alone works and gives the desired o\p.

When, i mix them i.e., calling c++ classes in A.c, it throws tons of errors related to old code.

In our makefile.am, we earlier used to have an option cc=gcc, now we changed it to cc=g++ after it thrown few errors. The makefile.am with make at the end creates a lib, let us say libx.a. The makefile.am  contains various earlier source files viz., A.c,x.c,y.c....

I fixed errors initially under A.c,x.c assuming that they are with new g++ compiler. Now,it started throwing errors under x.c, like this we have various source files.

Its very tedious to fix all of them. I believe iam missing some compiler flag options related to these errors. Now, majority of these errors are typecasting errors, where i converted them using static_cast etc. Apart from this, few misc errors. But, the code is a working code in c, its just mixing and changing makefile is throwing these errors.

Q:
1. How to get rid of those errors?
2. Is there any compiler flag which i need to use to continue working with minimal effort?
3. Is there some thing iam doing wrong in these process?
4. Any changes to makefile.am,you  people suggest?

Any help on this is appreciated. If Q is not clear, please let me know.

Note: We run our app using autoreconf,configure and make.

Regards,
Santhosh

Comment: What are the errors that are being printed out? Also, g++ should have no real issue compiling C code from my personal experience so knowing the errors would help greatly.

Comment: You should never assign `CC` or `CXX` in Makefile.am.  Those are user defined variables which should be assigned when configure is run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make will use either `$CC` or `$(CXX)` depending on the extension of the files, and can use both at the same time. For example, files ending in `*.cpp` are compiled with `$(CXX)`, files ending with `*.c` with `$(CC)`. So you don't have to set `cc` or `CC` globally to `g++` unless your `C` code is suitably modified to be compiled as C++.

Comment: juanchopanza: I tried the way you mentioned, i.e., i removed cc from makefile.am. Made the makefile. But, it was throwing lot of errors related to system includes EX:/usr/include/stdio.h

Comment: @Santhosh you should compile `C` code with `CC` and `C++` code with `CXX`.

Comment: I believe, i stated the question statement precisely. I have lot of source files which were working earlier and all are c files. Now, i have added code calling c++ classes. The Makefile.am does not have any CC flags. Its the configure which is creating Makefile.in and Makefile which has relevant CC flags. I am still getting the errors. I believe iam missing some simple thing. Let me know.

Comment: @Santhosh if your code is calling C++ classes, then it has to be compiled as C++ code. You can call C from C++, but not the other way around.